# Azure Event Hub Management programmatically (Java SDK)

Tags: java, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventhub

How i can programmatically create and delete event hubs? What maven dependency should be added?

I couldn't find anything in these for resource management

```
implementation group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-messaging-eventhubs', version: '5.16.1'
implementation group: 'com.azure.resourcemanager', name: 'azure-resourcemanager', version: '1.41.4'
```

Thanks for reply!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Azure Resource Manager Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/java/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager-eventhubs-readme?view=azure-java-stable) library.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure.resourcemanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-resourcemanager-eventhubs</artifactId>
    <version>2.32.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The link above provides more context and additional examples.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to run an example from the article

 `AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
    .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
    .build();
EventHubsManager manager = EventHubsManager
    .authenticate(credential, profile); `
but have error `DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder` class not found. Could you say where i can find it?

Comment: After adding this deps
`group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-identity', version: '1.11.0'
    group: 'com.azure', name: 'azure-core-http-netty', version: '1.13.10'`
have `nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MANAGED_HSM`
what version do you need to use to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're outside of my knowledge of Java already.   I'd suggest opening an issue in the repository so that the folks that work on the Java management packages can assist:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues